# php looping issue

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I would need your help with a looping issue, it's so annoying when the brain just stop functioning.

This is what I want to do:

1. I've got an array with some amount of data in it, lets say [6] in this case
2. From the length of this array I create a certain amount of divs. Each div will hold a maximum of 5 array values. So number of divs that will be created = round(sizeof array/5), so 2 divs in this case.

So far so good, but now to the part I can't figure out. How do I create the loop that prints out index 0-4 in div 1 and then goes forward and creates a second div to print out index 5-6 in.

And of course it should all be dynamically so if I've got 20 values in the array it will create and fill 4 divs with the values.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks everybody for your solutions!

Comment: `div will hold a maximum of 5 array values` please explain that sentence. As far i know `div` is HTML tag and div can't store array values

Comment: sorry, the array contains a number of values that the divs should be populated with, but one div should only be able to hold 5 "lines"(or values)

So let's say the array holds 6 names. Then the first div should be populated with the 5 first names and a second div with the last, sixth, name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: Untested code. Try this, though.

```
$perRow = 4;
$myContentArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$total = count($myContentArray);
$maxDivs = 3;

for($i = 0, $c = 0; $i < $total && $c <= $maxDivs; $i += $perRow + 1, $c++)
{
    echo '<div>';
    for($j = $i; $j <= $i + $perRow && $j < $total; $j++)
    {
        echo $myContentArray[$j] . ' ';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This prints out:

```
<div>1 2 3 4 5 </div><div>6 7 8 9 10 </div>
```

Comment: Hm, that did almost work. But for me it prints out
<div>1 2 3 4 5 </div><div>5 6 7 8 9</div><div>9 10</div>

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Is it easy to add the same mecanism to control the number of divs created? Say that I only would allow it to create 5 populated divs maximum? From there I could continue with the paging.

So if the array contains 30 values only 25 would be shown in five divs.

Comment: Updated with `$maxDivs` field which limits the number of divs to be outputted.

Comment: That's beautiful, and code I can relate to. Thanks again SpikeX!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at array_chuck, that splits the array into parts
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
// sample data
$rows = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

$chunks = array_chunk($rows, 3); // ajust to suit number of rows per chunk

foreach ($chunks as $chunk):
  echo '<div>';

  foreach ($chunk as $row):
    echo $row;
  endforeach;

  echo '</div>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: Who came through and downvoted all of these posts? `array_chunk` is one solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks bumper. Which solution would be the most efficient? Is there any downside with array_chunk?

Comment: `array_chunk` lets you use `foreach` which is a lot cleaner than a `for` loop.

Comment: @Josef the answers that use array_chunk, array_splice etc are slightly less efficient, as they duplicate the array into memory (5 bits at a time). but unless you are processing thousands of values you probably would not be able to see much difference in efficiency. Choose the solution that is easiest for your to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code:

1. Loop over array with counter
2. If counter = 0 or evenly divisible by 5, open `<div>`
3. Print array item

**Note:** A flag to determine if a `<div>` is open to check when to close is often helpful. Do this for step 2 and after the loop.

Comment: This sounds messy. Why not just use two nested loops?

Comment: Maybe, but mine's just one loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator (`%`) to check if a number is evenly divisible by another number.  In this case, `$x % 5 == 0` means `if the remainder of $x divided by 5 is equal to 0`.

```
<?php

$data = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","egg");

echo "<div>";
for($x=0; $x<count($data); $x++) {
    echo $data[$x];
    if ($x > 0 && $x % 5 == 0) {
        echo "</div><div>";
    }
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

**Edit:**  In response to your comment, I should've written it this way:

```
<?php

$data = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","egg");

echo "<div>";
for($x=1; $x<=count($data); $x++) {
    echo $data[$x-1];
    if ($x % 5 == 0) {
        echo "</div><div>";
    }
}
echo "</div>";

?>
```

Note the change of the `for` loop declaration, the change to how I accessed the array element of `$data`, and the modification to the conditional inside the loop.

Comment: This gives me 6 numbers in the first div and 4 in the second. But maybe I can play around with this.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I should have noted that I didn't test the code.  I made an edit to my post to show a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $data = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    echo '<div>';
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
        if ($i && $i % 5 == 0) {
            echo '</div><div>';
        }
        echo "$data[$i] ";
    }
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest and simplest solution

```
$array = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17);

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($array) ; $i += 5) {
    echo "<div>".join(" | ", array_slice($array, $i, 5))."</div>";
}
```

loop: take 5 elements from array, put in div, and join them by ' | '

[Working example](http://host9.info/ardiv.php)

Comment: Great example, if you do not need indexes (this may be something OP had in mind). Anyway, you should cache the `count()` result (calculate it before the loop, otherwise it will be executed every time and may seriously slow down the script, eg. when used for some specific object implementing `Countable` and `Iterable` interfaces).

Comment: check this http://host9.info/arrdiv2.php - array[1..100000]. This is why i don't cache `count()` results :) It doesn't matter...

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski i had never bothered to benchmark count() before, that is good information to know

Comment: @Peter, what are you talking about? Your benchmark showed caching count runs in a third of the time.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: You may not be aware the `count()` function depends on `count()` method of passed object, if it is implementing `Countable` interface, thus your benchmark is profoundly wrong. For your information: `count()` may be invoking processing-intensive operations. This is where my answer is a lot better than yours (and more flexible, as stated in the third line of my code).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I believe PeterSzymkowski is saying 50ms (or "2/3 of the time") is the amount of time that does not matter (another misunderstanding in my opinion). The second misunderstanding is that `count` not necessarily needs to be performed on array (and this is sometimes where it really matters).

Comment: Ok sorry guys. What i mean i don't care about caching `count()` on loop that go less than 100 runs, cause i don't care about 0,00004ms in script execution time.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: I believe you still do not follow my first comment, though. Are you aware the `count($data)` may be really time consuming, even if the result is less than `100`?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: I believe. To learn something new, you can read the documentation of [`count()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and if this still does not give you a clue, you can read the documentation of [`count()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php) and try to invent your own example proving what I was saying.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: Also it is good to read the manual, because there are often great tips, like the following: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#74758 (saying " __NEVER USE IN CYCLES!__ "[sic!])

Comment: ok guys, believe me i know this issue, but i really don't care about caching `count()` for simple loops like this example. In this case i rather like to see more simplificated code. (sorry for me english which is not perfect)

Comment: anyways i wonder why you post comment below my answer solution which is MUCH LESS resource expensive than other user solutions...

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple solutions. Mine is tested and works by using one container for each 5 elements of the data:

```
<?php

// any iterable data, not necessarily array
$data = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m');

$counter = 0;

foreach ($data as $data_part) {
    if ($counter % 5 === 0) {
        echo '<div>'; // open container (div?) here
    }
    echo '(' . $counter . ':' . $data_part . ')';
    if ($counter % 5 === 4) {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL; // close container (div?) here
    }
    $counter++;
}

if ($counter % 5 !== 4) {
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL; // close container (div) here, because unclosed
}
```

To see it in action (with `<div>` and `</div>` replaced respectively with `[` and `]`) just follow the link: http://codepad.org/GjMhiX5y

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski care to say why it is a disaster. calling it a disaster with no justification doesn't help anyone learn

Comment: Wow, this is *way* more code than you need. It's way too verbose.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski: Do not be sorry, just give some reason you think it is a disaster. Anything constructive (such as my criticism of your solution I have just posted)?

Comment: I really appreciate this site. In the matter of minutes you will have five answers and five different solutions. I think it's great! This did work as well. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Josef Not always... this was just a really easy question that a lot of people knew how to solve. If you ask something really technically complicated, you'll be lucky to get a single answer in a 24h period.

Answer (score -2):

in other words, you want to convert one-dimensional array to two-dimensional array, like this:

```
$array_one = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I");
$counter1 = 0;
$counter2 = 0;
foreach($array_one as $e) {
  $array_two[$couter1][$couter2] = $e;
  if($counter2==4) {
    $counter1++;
    $counter2 = 0;
  }
  else {
    $counter2++;
  }
}
```

or easier:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($array_one); $i++)
  $array_two[$i/5][$i%5] = $array_one[$i];
```